# How should I design the backend for my twitter app on android? - Could use some info

Tags: android, google-app-engine

Some may feel that this is a general question, but I don't believe that. I believe that this is a very important aspect of development and I am trying to learn from others.

Let's say I am making a clone of the twitter app.

Now, the front end is very do-able through traditional android code, however I don't know how to design the backend of the app.

I could use a database - but that seems better suited for older more traditional in house software applications.
I read a little about google app Engine, but I am not sure if that is a solution that should really be used for something like this.  Realistically I do not know what options I have and I could use some direction for my research - because I don't want to make a mistake in my architecture only to have to go back and redesign the backend.

I would like to know what types of things I should be researching so that I can evaluate my options appropriately.

Thanks

Comment: If you are trying to create only a clone of the Twitter app you would still use real Twitter API's, so I can't see the big deal with the backend (if you really need one). If you want to create a full clone of Twitter, have you tried to get information about the real one architecture?

Comment: but what if twitter didn't exist and I was building a twitter app from scratch?

Comment: Then you would faced the exactly same problems that Twitter folks faced building it! I really can't understand your question...

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you are looking at accessing the Twitter APIs to meet your functionality. You should look at an approach like the following:

- Do you want to clone the Twitter App as is ? or certain functionality of it ? Identify that stuff.
- Research the Twitter API in detail. For all your Twitter app needs, the requirement could be met directly by your API. Any local functionality for composing, replying, offline, etc can be met by your Android client itself and you do not necessarily need any backend functionality.
- If you are looking at providing more value added services (some examples are below) :

  - Analyze the Tweets to provide enhanced information
  - Combine Twitter Data with information from other data sources
  - Provide metrics for all users of your Twitter App
  - Set User Preferences such that you can sync these preferences to multiple devices if the user logs in from anywhere

  In such scenarios, doing work on the Server side will make things easier. Google App Engine is a great backend with which you can achieve a lot of the above functionality. It provides you a PaaS where you can use various services (datastore, networking, email) to boost your productivity, along with choices of languages (Java, Python, PHP and Go).

Comment: but what if twitter didn't exist and I was building a twitter app from scratch?

Comment: In that case, you have to do a much more extensive study of social networking platforms like Twitter, LinkedIn, Facebook and the kind of data + services they provide. That is too broad a scenario to discuss here and we cannot trivialize what they have achieved over a few Q&A.